# Isomorphism from $R[x,y] / (x, y - x^2)$ to $R$

Tags: ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I know that by the third isomorphism theorem $R[x,y] / (x, y - x^2)$ is isomorphic to $R$.  Therefore, $(x, y - x^2)$ should be the kernel of a homomorphism from $R[x,y]$ to $R$ by the first isomorphism theorem.  Since $x$ belongs to the kernel, it must be that $x$ goes to $0$.  However, I am struggling to see where $y$ should go.

Thanks!

Comment: $y-x^2$ is also in the kernel, so goes to zero, as does $x$. Now where does $y$ have to go?

Comment: I thought that it must mean y must go to zero as well.  Why isn't the kernel then (x, y)?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @DSUR The kernel **is** $(x,y)$.

Comment: But I need a homomorphism from R[x,y] to R whose kernel is (x, y - x^2) not (x,y)

Comment: @DSUR how are these two different?

Comment: oh x^2 belongs to (x, y- x^2) so that ideal really is (x, y), correct?

Comment: @DSUR You got it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Notice that $$(x,y-x^2)=(x,y-x^2,y-x^2+x^2)=(x,y)$$